# There is any alternative to rollback in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, command-line-interface

I am storing my all data in cassandra using cli . There is any possibility to rollback in cassandra or other technique please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get to the transactional behavior you are asking about is using [`BATCH`](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#batchStmt). Anyways the semantics of `BATCH` are not equivalent to an RDBMS transaction. Mainly:

> all updates in a BATCH belonging to a given partition key are performed atomically and in isolation